# Styled components nested rules don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Here is my folder structure:

```
type/
- Heading.js
- index.js

card/
- Card.js
- CardGroup.js
- index.js
```

JSX:

```
<CardGroup>
  <Heading>...</Heading>
  <Card>...</Card<
</CardHeading>
```

Now I am trying to style the `Heading` and `Card` components differently if they are nested inside a `CardGroup`. `CardGroup.js`:

```
import Heading from '../type';
import Card from './Card';

const CardGroup = styled.div`
  ${Heading} { ... }
  ${Card} { ... }
`;
```

Works OK for the `Heading` but NOT for the `Card`. I came accross this issue before and I can't wrap my head around what's causing this. Is it because the are in the same folder? Is it because of the order they are imported in my app? Any ideas would be really helpful.

Updated:

My `Card.js` implementation:

```
const StyledCard = styled.div`...`;

const Card = props => {
  ...
  <StyledCard {...props}>{props.children}</StyledCard>
}
```

Comment: Please show `Card` implementation

Comment: @DennisVash included a simplified example of `Card.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the component generated by `styled-component` (`StyledCard` in your example).

```
// Card.js
const ContainerCard = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
`;

const Card = ({ className }) => {
  return <ContainerCard className={className} />;
};

// Use any valid prop, Card.StyledComponent, Card.Style etc.
Card.className = ContainerCard;
export default Card;

// App.js
const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
`;

// Styling custom components, through className prop.
const VioletredRedCard = styled(Card)`
  background-color: palevioletred;
`;


// Target the component generated by styled-components
const CardWrapper = styled.div`
  ${Card.className} {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: paleturquoise;
  }
`;


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <CardWrapper>
        <Card />
      </CardWrapper>
      <VioletredRedCard />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

And, of course, [if you want to style the card via: `styled(Card)`](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components), be sure you pass the `className` prop like in the example above.

[image: Edit elated-ganguly-zz3qz]

Comment: Thanks dude, this helped a lot. I already pass all props with `{...props}` so I basically had to add `Card.className = StyledCard;` and `${Card.className}` when styling it.

Comment: Just notice that you don't have to use `className`, `Card.styledComponent = StyledCard;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use classname attr with styled components.

```
const Card = styled.div.attrs({
   className:"card"
})`
card styles
`
```

and you can use that className in CardGroup

```
const CardGroup=styled.div`
 & .card{}

`
```